# why machine learning algorithms don't handle categorical data and requires encoding categorical data into numerical data?

Tags: machine-learning

Always before using a dataset the categorical data encoding is made mandatory why?. why can't the machine learning models be created to handle categorical data directly?.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain this in a way you can understand.

A categorical variable is a variable whose values take on the value of labels.

For example, the variable may be **color** and may take on the values **red**, **green**, and **blue**.

Sometimes, one color has more impact in finding out the results than the other one, which means one color has more value than the other, so in order to assign it a value we need to convert it into numbers.

Also Machine learning algorithms and deep learning neural networks require that input and output variables are numbers.

This means that categorical data must be encoded to numbers before we can use it to fit and evaluate a model.

Comment: Of course, internally, categorical data is represented (after loading) as numbers anyway - they are just ordinal numbers, and are assigned according to whatever data import scheme the application implements. But any sort of a programming or data handling language can use being type-safe. And thus implicit conversion from category strings to numbers is not normally desired. But the conversion is usually trivial if all you want is to map, say, sorted category strings to ordinal numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much Raj and Monica, it means a lot to me.